# How to approach a quiz mechanic in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a simple quiz app in Codeigniter where the user is presented an image and they are to guess if it's right or wrong. Similar to 'hot or not'.

There are 25 questions, all either Yes or No answers. I could take the easy option of creating 25 pages and carry over previous results in hidden fields but this seems a bit longwinded and silly.

I have a view file where the only thing that changes is the image. So I'm thinking I can pass in the image path as a variable and change it dynamically but I cannot work out at a more abstract level how to record the result of each answer and then at the end show the results and insert into a database.

The problem I'm having is how to load the next image in the sequence and record that result.

P.s

The images will always be in the same order. It doesn't really matter if they are random, although that would be nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish that, by inserting the questions on your database, with the following fields:

ID - the id of the question.
Image - the name of the image for this question for example "question1Image.jpg"
Correct Answer - the correct answer for this question, if the answers are all YES/NO you can use an INT. 1 for YES and 0 for NO.

Now that you have your questions on your database, on your controller e may create something like this:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Quizz extends CI_Controller {
    public function questions($idquestion){
        $this->load->model('questions_model');
        //fetch the questions from the database
        $questions = $this->questions_model->get_questions();
        //if it's a post we'll check if the answer is correct and pass the next question to the view
        if($this->input->post()){
            $answered_question = $this->questions_model->get_question($idquestion-1);
            $question = $this->questions_model->get_question($idquestion);

            if($answered_question['correct_answer']==$this->input->post('answer')){
                //if the user answered correctly do something here
            }
            $data['question'] = $question;
            //the id of the next question you'll use it for the next post
            $data['next_question'] = $idquestion+1;
            $this->load->view('your_view', $data);
        }
        //it's the first time the user uses this so we'll load the first answer
        else{
            $question = $this->questions_model->get_question(1);

            $data['question'] = $question;
            //the id of the next question you'll use it for the next post
            $data['next_question'] = 2;
            $this->load->view('your_view', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

On your view you can have something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Question page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php //we'll use the codeigniter form helper to generate manually the form
    echo form_open('quizz/questions/'.$next_question); ?>
    <!-- This will load the image dynamically-->
    <img src="<?=base_url('public/images/'.$question['image'])?>">

    <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">YES</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="0">NO</label>
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
    <?=form_close();?>
</body>
</html>
```

The model:

```
<?php
class questions_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function get_questions()
    {   
        return $this->db->get('questions_table')->result_array();
    }
    public function get_question($idquestion)
    {   
        $this->db->select('questions_table.*');
        $this->db->from('questions_table');
        $this->db->where('questions_table.id', $idquestion);
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of an INT, I'd save space by using either a TINYINT or a BIT (depending on the DB)

Comment: Ok, Thanks how would my model look for this?

Comment: I've added the model, have you ever worked with codeigniter? Because you have to do some minor configs before using this code. Oh and this is just a guide I don't think that this code will work out of the box

Comment: yeah sorry. I have written a model and the code works as you intended now. But I still have one question. I need to store the answers until the end of the quiz and then echo out the result. Where would i do this?

Comment: you can create a session and store there the answers, on the controller you have that if that checks if the user answered right. I advise you to read the session documention on the condeginiter http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html or you could use regular php sessions

Comment: Thanks, I have it working good now. I just kept 'correct' in the session and incremented it by one for every correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you got two options , with Ajax or without Ajax.

easy one first, without ajax :

best way to pass data from each question to other one is by using session variable to sort it.
for example you sort the answer in an array called $answers something like this :

```
$answers = $this->session->userdata('answers');
$answers[] = ** NEW ANSWER HERE **
$this->session->set_userdata('answers', $answers);
```

in order to get images you can sort all questions ( images ) in an array in your controller/model and check how many items your $answers in your session contains to determine which image is to be shown next ! simple as that ! :-)

now with ajax, everything will be almost the same only thing that changes is that you need to be a little bit handy with jquery/js in order not to refresh the page and just change the image ( question ).

hope it helped.

Comment: Ok the idea makes sense. How would my controller look? So for example do I have a form in my view that submits to the same method all the time? This is the part im finding confusing to work out. Thanks

Comment: Exactly ! dont worry you have got it correctly ! you can just keep posting the form to the same page and by reviewing the session and adding to it each time user answers you can keep track of questions and determine which question should be asked next !
dont forget that key to explore and discover new thing in our field is to test, test, test and test ! :-) so keep testing whatever crazy idea hits your brain !
if you had any questions dont hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

By creating your quiz in a database to store answers with basic tables like :

```
| question   |
|============|
| id (PK)    |
| no         |
| image_path |

| choice      |
|=============|
| id (PK)     |
| question_id |
| value       |

| answer              |
|=====================|
| user_id (PK, FK)    |
| question_id (PK, FK)|
| choice_id (PK, FK)  |

| user                |
|=====================|
| id (PK)             |
| session_id or email |
```

With a schema like this you can easily use the key `no` to present the questions in a coherent order or `RAND()` for a randomized order. The choice is optionnal, but if you ever want to extend your quiz you can use it to expand the choices.

To find the next question for a given user could be something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM question as q 
JOIN answer as a
  ON q.id = a.question_id 
WHERE q.id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM answer WHERE user_id = :user_id) 
  AND a.user_id = :user_id 
ORDER BY q.no -- or ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

This way you will get the first question that the user hasn't answered yet. Other than that, it's up to you how much info you want to keep about your user.

**EDIT (to add from first comment)**

You will need 2 actions in your controller, one to fetch what to display and sent id to the view and the other to grab the data from the user and store it to the DB.

In your model you will need 2 methods (at least) which would be one to get the next question and one to save the answer. I don't know the specifics of code igniter but here are the main lines:

```
Controller:
displayAction()
    get user id from user model (through session variable or session id)
        If you don't have a reference for the user, you need to create one and return it
    get next question from question model (user id as param)
    send the question data to the view

saveAction()
    get user id (through session variable or session id)
    get question id (from get or post param)
    if you use a database to store choices, validate that the choice is possible, based on the current question
    send user id, question id and the choice made to the answer model for storage
    redirect to displayAction()
```

Comment: This seems like a good way to go. So, I have one view file, in there a form with the options yes or no. This would point to a method in my controller. But, what would I have that method do?