# codeigniter method get losing data on controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have aa application where i can edit fields of a database table. Everything is fine and the data is updated, except if i go to the field that i want to update and instead of changing the text, put the field blank. In that way i get php errors because (i guess) the method of my controller lose the id of that row of the table:

I would be glad if anyone could help me, thank's in advance.

Part of the view file where i use the method get to pass the id of the table row (edit_fuga.php).

```
 <div id='tab2'>    
            <?php
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM fugas WHERE tipo_fuga='2';");

            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='id_fuga' value='". $row['id_fuga']."'>";
                echo $row['desc_fuga']."&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class='button' href='http://localhost/code/index.php/fugas/editar_fuga?var1=".$row['id_fuga']."'>Editar</a>";
                echo "<br/>";
            }

            ?>


        </div>
```

The view to where i am redirected (editar_fuga.php):

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('fugas/editar_fuga') ?>

<?php 

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT desc_fuga_table FROM tipos_fuga where tipo_fuga_table='".$fuga_selected['tipo_fuga']."';");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->desc_fuga_table;
}

$tipo_fuga_selected=$row->desc_fuga_table;

    ?>

    <label for="tipo_fuga"><?php echo $tipo_fuga_selected; ?></label><br/>
    <p/>


    <label for="desc_fuga">Desc da fuga:</label><p/> 
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="desc_fuga"><?php echo $fuga_selected['desc_fuga']; ?></textarea><p/>

    <input type="hidden" name="id_fuga" value="<?php echo $fuga_selected['id_fuga']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Alterar Fuga" /><p/>

    <INPUT Type="button" VALUE="Voltar" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">

</form>
```

The method on the controller of the view editar_fuga.php

```
public function editar_fuga(){

        $fuga_id = $this->input->get('var1');
        var_dump($fuga_id);

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        //$this->load->view('templates/header');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc_fuga', 'Descrição da fuga acidental', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $data['fuga_selected'] = $this->fugas_model->get_fuga($fuga_id);        
        $this->load->view('fugas/editar_fuga', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->fugas_model->update_fuga();
        echo "Fuga alterada com sucesso.<br/><br/>";
        $this->load->view('fichas/index');
        }

    }
```

Fuga Model:

```
    public function update_fuga(){



    $data = array(
        'desc_fuga' => $this->input->post('desc_fuga')
    );

    $id=$this->input->post('id_fuga');

    $this->db->where('id_fuga', $id);
    $this->db->update('fugas', $data);

}

public function get_fuga($fuga_id){

    var_dump($fuga_id);

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM fugas where id_fuga='".$fuga_id."';");

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $data_fuga = array(
    'id_fuga' => $row['id_fuga'],
    'tipo_fuga' => $row['tipo_fuga'],
    'desc_fuga' => $row['desc_fuga']
    );
    }

    return $data_fuga;

}
```

Comment: What PHP errors are you getting exactly?

Comment: Undefined variable: data_fuga Filename: models/fugas_model.php

Undefined variable: row Filename: fugas/editar_fuga.php

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: fugas/editar_fuga.php

Comment: If you are using hidden fields for the ID, that doesn't make sense. Maybe because the field is blank it tries to insert a null value to your database and in your structure that field doesn't allow null values. If you could paste the error it would be nice.

Comment: can you post the code of your model? I've noticed that you're fetching data on your view and that's something you shouldn't be doing

Comment: Dont mind the hidden field, i add it later because i was getting this problem and tryed something without the get method.

Can it be because first time i load the page like this:
http://localhost/code/index.php/fugas/editar_fuga?var1=".$row['id_fuga']."'

and in the second time (when the validation goes false), i load like this:

$data['fuga_selected'] = $this->fugas_model->get_fuga($fuga_id);        
        $this->load->view('fugas/editar_fuga', $data);

and he doesnt get the var1 on the url?

I will post the model, just a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here, this is bad a practice. You shouldn't mix views and database access

This method should be in your model

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT desc_fuga_table FROM tipos_fuga where tipo_fuga_table='".$fuga_selected['tipo_fuga']."';");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->desc_fuga_table;
}

$tipo_fuga_selected=$row->desc_fuga_table;

    ?>
```

And because you're not passing $fuga_selected['tipo_fuga'] on the second time, you won't get any results, that means the query will be empty, that saying $row will never instantiated

so the line that gives error is this

```
$tipo_fuga_selected=$row->desc_fuga_table;
```

And as @tix3 said, you should read more about MVC, because you're messing a little bit

Comment: but if i put that method on my model will it fix the error then? How can i call it on the view then?

Comment: No,because on the second time you must pass the $fuga_selected['tipo_fuga']. You could do that by changing the way you call form open on your view 
<?php echo form_open('fugas/editar_fuga/'.$fuga_selected['tipo_fuga']) ?>

ANd you don't call the method of the model on the view you call it on your controller and the pass that data to the view

Comment: In this answer I gave you can see how you could use the mvc pattern http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070099/how-to-approach-a-quiz-mechanic-in-codeigniter/15070760#15070760

Comment: Thanks Fabio, i have it solved now, and i passed that query to the model and i'm calling it now on the controller to send it to the view, so it solved the tipo_fuga problem. But what i really was missing (and pretending help) was this part:
<?php echo form_open('fugas/editar_fuga/'.$fuga_selected['tipo_fuga']) ?>
to solve the blank field error of losing the id on the update. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I hope that you've learned a bit more MVC, so you can improve your skills before you create bad habits. In small applications the spaghetti code fits the purpose, although it's not the best approach, it does the job, but on big applications that's something you should never do because it's harder to make future changes, it's harder for you to read it and for your colleagues

Answer (score 0):

To start with you are doing thing TOTALLY wrong.

You should read some of the tutorials on what MVC is.

You should NEVER do database action in your view file, for NO reason.
You should start by reading the excellent codeigniter user guide and some generic articles on what MVC really is: Example from wikipedia is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

You should also take a look on active record on codeigniter so that you can use instead of `->query()` which is strongly discouraged and should only be used in some rare situations that there are some really complex queries that cannot be done with AR.

*** Edit after some comments**

Active record is a personal preference but I believe that it is way easier and safer for a novice to use, as the inputs are automatically escaped.And yes codeigniters AR is not an actual Active Record implementation but it is still better than bare sql.

All in all keep your logic on the controller, your database interaction on your model and your html (and some minor viewing logic) in your view.

Comment: Since when has it been bad to *not* use an included active record object? It's down to personal choice, please don't force your own style of building queries on everyone.

Comment: he is not including an active record object he's querying on the view

Comment: @BenGriffiths you are probably correct (I will edit the answer and note that this is personal preference) but I will stand by it as it automatically escapes most of the input, and it is probably easier and safer for a novice user.The issue here though is that he is querying IN THE VIEW which is just breaking MVC.

Comment: I don't disagree that its a great tool to use, I just don't like it when people say it's bad practice to not use AR. I agree with the MVC standpoint however.