# Quiz Approach in Codeigniter Gone wrong

Tags: php, codeigniter

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070099/how-to-approach-a-quiz-mechanic-in-codeigniter) Question, im also creating an quiz approach in Codeigniter. here is the snippet of my code.
Controller :

```
function quiz(){
    $this->load->model('belajar_model');
    $data['data']=$this->belajar_model->quiz();
    $this->load->view('quiz',$data);
}

function getQuiz($id){
    $this->load->model('belajar_model');
    $data['data']=$this->belajar_model->getQuiz($id);
    $this->load->view('quiz',$data);

 $this->load->model('belajar_model');
    $data['data']=$this->belajar_model->quiz();
    if($this->input->post()){
        $jawab = $this->belajar_model->getQuiz($id);
        $soal = $this->belajar_model->getQuiz($id);

        if($jawab['benar']==$this->input->post('jawab')){

        }
        $data['jawab'] = $soal;
        $data['next'] = $id+1;
        $this->load->view('quiz', $data);
    }

    else{
        $jawab = $this->belajar_model->getQuiz(1);

        $data['soal'] = $soal;
        $data['next'] = 2;
        $this->load->view('quiz', $data);
    }
}
```

and here is the model :

```
function quiz(){
    //$this->db->where('id = 1');
    $query = $this->db-> get('kuis');
    return $query->result_array();
}

function getQuiz($data){
    $this->db->where('id',$data);
    $query = $this->db-> get('kuis');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

and here is the snippet of the view (my friend did the view) :

```
    <h3>Pilihlah salah satu jawaban yang benar!</h3>

<?php foreach ($data as $list){
    echo"<p>".$list['soal']."</p>"; 

    echo"<table>
        <tr><td><label><input type='radio' name='jawab' value='a'>".$list['ansA']."</label></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label><input type='radio' name='jawab' value='b'>".$list['ansB']."</label></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label><input type='radio' name='jawab' value='c'>".$list['ansC']."</label></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label><input type='radio' name='jawab' value='d'>".$list['ansD']."</label></td></tr>
        ";
    }?>
    <tr><td><button type='submit' >Submit</button><td></tr><table>
```

after trying to implement it, with some modification make it work on the page, the page is jumbled like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILBUK.png), it's jumbled because the question and the answer is not displayed correctly. it also didn't receive the inputs from the quiz and there are some errors displayed.

my question is : where did it go wrong? is it from the view or either the models/controller not right? FYI, some of the attributes are written on my native language(Indonesian) to fulfill my studies, to make the code understandable to both my friend and my lecturer.

thanks for answering! it'll means a lot for me to get the webpage work because it's my final project and i didn't adapt enough (yet) in php and codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Before going further, you should first clean your code to make sure you don't have any unforseable side effects:

In your getQuiz() method in your controller, you load your model two times and you also render the view twice. Once at the beginning and once after you checked the presence of $this->input->post().

PS for the mods: I know this is more comment material, but I can't comment yet.